# Interface as generic constraint, access property of interface (c#)

Tags: c#, generics

I want to access a property of a generic object which implements the following interface:

```
public interface IAnimal{
    string AnimalType { get; set; }
}

public class Animal<T> where T : IAnimal{
    public String GetAnimalType<T>(T a){

        return a.AnimalType; // AnimalType is not visible by compiler. How can I access it?
    }
}
```

When I try to get AnimalType property I get a compiler error. 
Who can I access this property?

Comment: Remove `T` from `GetAnimalType<T>`, It hides type parameter for class. Use `GetAnimalType(T a)`

Comment: Because you're declaring the method as a generic method, thus redeclaring T without a generic constraint. Remove `<T>` from the GetAnimalType method definition.

Comment: the reason is int the comments above Remove <T> but you can always do: `return (a as IAnimal).AnimalType;`

Comment: @jonathana Why would you suggest a run-time cast when the OP is looking for a compile-time check?

Comment: Thanks it is work!